# Database design: How to handle cancelled orders but save the order history

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

How can the following scenario be handled with a database?

There are the following database relations:

### User

has many Orders
has many Tickets

### Order

has many Payments
has many OrderItems

### Ticket

belongs to OrderItem
belongs to User
belongs to TicketCategory

### TicketCategory

has many tickets

A ticket is created in the database whenever a user places an order. How can the case be handled here when a payment fails or a user leaves the page in the payment process? I would actually like to create only tickets that belong to a successful order, but otherwise it is not possible to determine which tickets were attempted to be purchased in the case of an aborted payment (order history).

Is there a missing intermediate table like reservations or something?

Comment: The question, "How to handle cancelled orders?" is answered by adding a cancelled flag to the Order row. "Is there a missing intermediate table like reservations?"  Probably. If you take reservations, you need a table to store the reservation information.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain to me how I could supplement my scheme so that this works with the reservations? Should a ticket only be created after a successful purchase or should the number of tickets be inserted in the database without a UserID when an event is created?

Comment: I don't have enough information about your domain to elaborate further.  Are tickets for one event or multiple events.  Are users expected to buy a group of tickets (like a season ticket, one for each event) or single ticket, single events only?  Do the events have assigned seating or just a capacity?  I may have additional questions, but for now, those should be sufficent.

Comment: Tickets are always only for one single event and users are expected to buy one or multiple tickets (eg. basic ticket, pro ticket) at once which can be from different ticket categories of the same event. The categories do not have seating numbers and are just tracking its capacity. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a User table with a User ID and an Event table with an Event ID.

Each event has a number of tickets for sale.  First, let's define a ticket category table.

```
TicketCategory
--------------
TicketCategory ID
TicketCategory Name
```

Where you have a basic ticket, pro ticket, etc.  The price of the tickets isn't included here because they can be different from event to event.

Next, let's create an event ticket junction table;

```
EventTicket
-----------
EventTicket ID
Event ID
TicketCategory ID
Ticket Price
Total Tickets
Tickets Reserved
Tickets Sold
```

I give every table an auto-incrementing integer ID primary key.  It makes joins simpler.

You have an Event ID, TicketCategory ID unique index for each type of ticket sold at an event.  You can also have a TicketCategory ID, Event ID unique index for reporting purposes.

The total tickets integer value is set when the event is set up and does not change unless the capacity of the event changes.

The tickets reserved integer value is the number of tickets reserved but not bought.

The tickets sold integer value is the number of tickets sold.  I'm assuming that cancelled orders are relatively rare.  If you wish, you can add a tickets paid integer value to track the number of tickets ordered but not paid for.

When seeing how many tickets are available for sale, you take the reserved and sold ticket count and subtract them from the total ticket count.

Now, let's deal with a ticket order.  Generally, you have an Order table and an OrderLineItem table.

```
Order
-----
Order ID
User ID
Event ID
Order Timestamp
Status (Active, Paid, Cancelled)

OrderLineItem
-------------
OrderLineItem ID
Order ID
TicketCategory ID
Quantity
Ticket Price Per Ticket
```

The Order table has a unique index on User ID, Event ID, Order Timestamp descending, and Status.  The OrderLineItem table has a unique index on Order ID, TicketCategory ID.

You calculate the order line item total by multiplying the quantity by the ticket price per ticket.  You calculate the total order amount by calculating all the order line item totals.

A reservation table could look like this:

```
Reservation
-----------
Reservation ID
User ID
Event ID
TicketCategory ID
Quantity
Reservation Timestamp
```

You would have a User ID, Event ID. TicketCategory ID unique index.  I'll leave the additional possible unique indexes up to you.

When a reservation is made, the ticket quantity in the EventTicket table is reduced.

When an order is placed, you first check if a reservation had been made.  If so, you delete the reservation rows and create the order rows.  If not, you create the order rows.  Either way, you make the proper adjustments in the EventTicket table.

Comment: Thanks. How about the Tickets table? How could I lookup the cancelled order history of a user?

Comment: @Fabio: SELECT from Order WHERE User Id = AND Status = Cancelled